# Delphi XE2: firemonkey and playing video

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, vlc, firemonkey, libvlc

I am succedd to playing video on firemonkey using with vlc. But I have a problem with 3D forms.
If I am using my own video component with "Firemonkey HD Application" I have no problem, but when I want to use it with  "Firemonkey 3D Application" I have problem with video vibrational:(

How can I stop the FMX controls self painting ?

thanks

Comment: What happens when you put your control on a TLayer3D component?

Comment: Nothing happen cause it just a FMX TPanel object,  actually i integrate a window handle to firemonkey control on runtime, and i actually still using like a VCL control. I just create a window using with windows api (CreateWindowEx) and i set the parent of this child window to the parent form with parent form handle.